# vscode debugger configuration: cwd

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb, lldb, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to configure a debugger for my project.
Here is the problem.

The project folder structure can be simplified like this:

```
 - Project Root
     - X
     - Y
     - etc
```

I absolutely need to set the cwd in the debugger config as X, otherwise the binary won't run. If I set it as X, program runs, debugger (sort of) works: I see the call stack and the values of the variables. However, vscode cannot find the files with code and I can't see the lines being executed. VSCode also gives me an error:

```
Unable to open 'file.cpp':
Unable to read file '/blahblah/cwd/Y/file.cpp'
Error: unable to resolve non-existing file.
```

So the debugger rightfully uses the cwd as a prefix to the rest of the file path, but Y is not nested into X, it is actually in the same root directory.

Again, I absolutely need the binary to be called from the X directory. Is there any way to tell vscode the proper path to the code files in this case?

Comment: This sounds like a problem with how your project is compiled.  The compiler can choose to report a source location relative to some directory, but it is supposed to list that directory along with the relative path so that debuggers can resolve the source paths correctly.  Sounds like that is not being done or not being done in a way lldb understands.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: Note also, in lldb you can set the "debugee working directory" separately from the debugger's cwd (e.g. the -w option to `process launch`).  I don't know if VSCode lets you add this option to the launch action, but that might be a way to work around the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if this has to do with the compilation of the project. And anyway I wouldn't want to mess with the compilation, as the project is very large and compilation is quite complex. We're using bazel to build it, but I'm not sure if the compiler is gcc or clang. However, this "debugee" vs the "debugger" working directory sounds exactly like what I'm looking for! Thank you so much, I'll investigate into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is what worked for me:

```
// added this to launch.json
"sourceFileMap: {
    "/proc/self/cwd" : "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

From the VSCode docs:

> sourceFileMap:
> This allows mapping of the compile-time paths for source
> to local source locations. It is an object of key/value pairs and will
> resolve the first string-matched path. (example: "sourceFileMap": {
> "/mnt/c": "c:\" } will map any path returned by the debugger that
> begins with /mnt/c and convert it to c:\. You can have multiple
> mappings in the object but they will be handled in the order
> provided.)

My problem was that the directory from which I needed the process to run didn't match the directory where the source files are located. In the error message vscode gave me I saw the path it uses to try to find source files ("/proc/self/cwd"). So I mapped this path to the one I actually need (just the workspaceFolder in my case).

Comment: Note, it isn't usual to build with relative paths in debug information because it causes precisely the problem you encountered.  OTOH, if you have a distributed build environment, (e.g. bazel) the paths to the source files are unlikely to be the same on the builders as on your desktop, so the debug info can't use absolute paths.  Such environments instruct the compiler to emit them relative to the project to work around that problem.  Glad you found the sourceFileMap solution, that's what you have to do in this case.